# Wikidata SPARQL is using BIND instead of FILTER

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I used Wikidata's query generator to get a list of people born on 18th May 1958. The query is reproduced below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P569 ?statement_0.
      ?statement_0 psv:P569 ?statementValue_0.
      ?statementValue_0 wikibase:timePrecision ?precision_0.
      ?statementValue_0 wikibase:timeValue ?P569_0.
      BIND("+1958-05-18T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime AS ?P569_0)
    }
    LIMIT 100
  }
}
```

It works and gives me 93 people born on that date. https://w.wiki/8cZG

My problem is that I do not understand why it is using BIND, and not FILTER.  Reading the manual, I think the code should be retrieving everyone with a birth date, and overwriting their birth date with 1958-05-18. I have not found anything in the manual that uses BIND as a filter.

Please can anyone explain?

Comment: `BIND` is used to provide inline data. That said it is not a filter. `BIND` in SPARQL always closes the group graph pattern, i.e. it goes on top of all patterns in the same {} block which precede it, see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind - in your case this means the value of `?P569_0` is already bound to the given data and this is usually also way more efficient than a filter which might happen later in the query execution.

Comment: It would be the same as writing `?statementValue_0 wikibase:timeValue "+1958-05-18T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime . ` and omitting the `BIND` clause in your query. It's just more generic for query builders to pre-prend or append such a `BIND` clause.

Comment: By the way, technically, the `BIND` should be put before the ` ?statementValue_0 wikibase:timeValue ?P569_0.` , e.g. at the beginning of the subquery. According to the SPARQL specs the current query would be invalid as its assigning a value via `BIND` to a variable that's already been bound during query execution. Maybe the query optimizer of Blazegraph doesn't care and reorder anyways for of efficiency reasons.

Comment: Thank you.   ?statementValue_0 wikibase:timeValue "+1958-05-18T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime .     was the lightbulb moment.   Realising that this was the line that was doing the filtering, and the BIND was superfluous, has made it all clear.